# JQuery .trigger('click'), .click(), .triggerHandler('click') not working in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, triggers, click

I have a simple JQuery code that will check the current URL and search for a text; if it exists, execute some code. I am using switch Case. The code works in FF, IE but not in Webkit browsers, Chrome and Safari. Here is the code:

NB: Please assume the current URL include #f3 at the end - so case

```
$(document).ready(function() {      

    var checkUrl = $(location).attr('href');

        switch (true) {

        case (checkUrl.search("#f1") > 0):
            //just focus on #f3 below
            break;

        case (checkUrl.search("#f2") > 0):
            //just focus on #f3 below
            break;

        case (checkUrl.search("#f3") > 0):
            //$(".jcarousel-next").trigger("click");
            $(".jcarousel-next").triggerHandler('click');

            break;

        default:
            false;

        }
});
```

What this should do is simulate a `div` with class `".jcarousel-next"` being clicked on the page. Chrome and Safari does nothing (apart from just loading the page). Works in Firefox, IE etc...

Any solution guys?

Comment: the assumption you are having us make isn't really that safe. Have you confirmed that yourself using console.log? `console.log(checkUrl)`. Also, why not just use `location.href` instead of `$(location).attr(`?

Comment: Just to be clear, triggerHandler works just fine in safari and chrome, the problem must be elsewhere, either in the selector being used, the event being triggered, or in the code path to get there.

Comment: Thanks for the input so far guys. Here's what I have tried since:
1. Pasted entire code in Chrome console = works / executes fine!
2. Pasted just code snippet in console ($(".jcarousel-next").triggerHandler('click');) or the trigger etc.. = works / executes fine
3. Used location.href instead of $(location).attr in JS file = behaves the same, won't work in Chrome / Safari

Comment: have you confirmed that you are actually getting to the triggerHandler

Comment: @KevinB - yes, I have tried different variations of the following: $("#carousel-next-btn").trigger('click', alert($("#carousel-next-btn"))); - this will alert "[object Object]" and then simulate the clicking of the button to change the Carousel. Chrome will do the same as all other browsers but won't do the "click" part of it Note, tried using ID instead of Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the code and now works for all required browsers (ie7, ie8, ie9, FF, Chrome & Safari). This is an example of what will sit in one of the cases (case2):

for (var i =1; i <2; i++) { 
 setTimeout(function () { $(".jcarousel-next").click();  }, 700 * i); 
}

The for loop will action the required code for a certain number of times with a sort of interval to to delay the clicking, otherwise, the loop happens so quick you don't see it.

Thanks to all for their suggestions.

Abu K.

Answer (score 0):

trigger works fine in all browser, I think the problem is because the selector it's a class, so if the "jcarousel-next" it's added on runtime it's necessary add the handler after

here is a example and works fine
first text do nothing.
second raise click event from third.
third has click event...

runnning.... http://jsfiddle.net/37dAj/

```
<div class="botton1">
    <h2>nothing</h2>
</div>

<div class="botton2">
    <h2>raise click event from botton3</h2>
</div>

<div class="botton3">
    <h2>click event</h2>
</div>​

$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.botton3').click(doSomething);
        $('.botton2').click(doTrigger);
    });

    function doTrigger() {
        $('.botton3').trigger('click');
    }

    function doSomething() {
        alert('boo!');
    }
```